# How to handle child http request for collection in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

in my service.ts I read bookmarks.json that contains a list of bookmarks.

And for each bookmark I want to set a favicon by calling

```
https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=...
```

Here is the function that does the job

```
    getBookmarks() {
        return this.$http.get('data/bookmarks.json').then((response: any) => {
            let bookmarks = response.data;
            bookmarks.forEach(bookmark => {
                    this.$http.get('https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' + bookmark.url).then(response2 => {
                        bookmark.icon = response2.data;
                    })
            });
            return bookmarks;
        });
    };
```

Obviously I am not doing this right.

The code never hits the line

```
bookmark.icon = response.data;
```

**What am I doing wrong? Thank you.**

I get same set of errors for each bookmark:

> Possibly unhandled rejection:
>   {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://app.pluralsight.com/library/","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}

If I just set:

```
bookmark.icon = 'https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=' + bookmark.url;
```

then I still get a bunch of requests with 400 error code

looks like its the same issue...

[image]

**UPDATE**

Stupid me :)

This works like a charm :)

```
<img ng-src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain={{bookmark.url}}" />
```

Comment: Are you getting a 200 status code back from the request? Also I think you want `bookmark.icon = response2.data` but obviously that isn't related to the problem

Comment: just do something like `bookmark.icon = "https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com"`

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting something similar to this in the console log: `preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` which if true means there isn't much you can do other than try to get google to make some server changes or change your approach

Comment: use it like a Url

Comment: I will try something else....

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running into a CORS issue on that request.  Your best bet is to save the actual URL to the bookmark.icon and then use that source for whenever you need to display it.

```
<img ng-src='{{ bookmark.icon }}'></img>
```

Comment: Just tried that, but I guess its the same problem, updated my post with a screenshot...

Comment: @monstro Looking at that screenshot something is going very wrong with the domain query string